# phpspec Could not open input file

Tags: laravel-4, phpspec

I have just installed phpspec into my Laravel project with composer, but when I try running `phpspec` I get this error:

```
Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/development/myproject/vendor/phpspec/phpspec/bin/phpspec
```

It's the same when I try to run it without alias from `vendor/bin/phpspec`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that you are in this path, if not please navigate

> /cygdrive/c/development/myproject/

If yes, then you hit the full path of phpspec inside vendor:

> $ vendor/phpspec/phpspec/bin/phpspec

For example:

> $ vendor/phpspec/phpspec/bin/phpspec --version

Will show your phpspec's version there.